# Acessing shared memory between the PRU and beagle bone

Tags: linux, kernel, beagleboneblack

I need your help

I am having some problems in accessing the PRU shared registers on the Beaglebone side.

So, I am writing in the desired memory addresses on the PRU side ( I can verify it be using the prudebug tool provided here: https://markayoder.github.io/PRUCookbook/ , which I can use to check the content of the PRU registers). But the trouble comes when I try to access it from the arm side: in the Pru, I have written the value 0xED in the registers 0x10000, however, in the arm side I am unable to read it.

I think I have to use the mmap function of the kernel to get access of physical memory addresses, but might I been doing something wrong on the usage of the function itself. Can anyone shed some light on what might be happening here?

PRU side:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pru_cfg.h>
#include "resource_table_empty.h"

#define PRU_SHARED_MEM_ADDR 0x00010000

void main(void)
{
    // enable OCP
    CT_CFG.SYSCFG_bit.STANDBY_INIT = 0;
    volatile int* buffer = (volatile int *) PRU_SHARED_MEM_ADDR;
    buffer[0] = 0xED;
    /* Clear SYSCFG[STANDBY_INIT] to enable OCP master port->Shared memory */
    CT_CFG.SYSCFG_bit.STANDBY_INIT = 0;
}
```

Arm side:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define DDR_BASEADDR   0x10000
#define OFFSET_DDR     0x00

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int mem_fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
   if (mem_fd == -1){
        printf("Err");
        return 0;
   }
   volatile void *ddrMapp = NULL;
   volatile void *DDR_regaddr1 = NULL;

   ddrMapp = mmap(0, 0x0FFFFFFF, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, mem_fd, DDR_BASEADDR);

   DDR_regaddr1 = ddrMapp + OFFSET_DDR;
   printf("PRU address: %X\n", &DDR_regaddr1); // returns 0xBEFFFB00
   return(0);
 }
```

ps: Here's the documentation of mmap function: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your kernel revision, I would suggest to use the **PRU Linux Application Loader**:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PRU_Linux_Application_Loader_API_Guide

So that you can

```
    /* Get pointers to PRU local memory */
    void *pruDataMem;
    prussdrv_map_prumem(PRUSS0_PRU0_DATARAM, &pruDataMem);
    unsigned int *pruData = (unsigned int *) pruDataMem;
```

and access data in PRU RAM as pruData[0] etc.